# representing a weighted graph using hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

My input text file:

```
  122334 
  45   
  67
```

Output should be:

```
0-{1=2,2=3,3=4} //node 0 is connected to 1 with weight 2,to 2 with weight 3,etc

1-{4=5}

2-{6=7}
```

Below is my program:

```
public class BFS {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer>>hash1=new HashMap<Integer,     HashMap<Integer,Integer>>();
        HashMap<Integer, Integer>hash2=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        HashMap<Integer, Integer>temp1=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Translab\\workspace\\Algorithms\\inputfile.txt"));
        int remainder,remainder2,j=0;
        int line=1;
        String str;
        while ((str =in.readLine()) != null) {
            int foo = Integer.parseInt(str);
          while(foo>0){
                 remainder=foo % 10;
                   foo = foo / 10;
                 remainder2=foo%10;
                 foo=foo/10;
                 temp1.put(remainder2, remainder);
                 hash2.putAll(temp1);

        }
        temp1.clear();
        hash1.put(j, hash2);

        j++;


        }
        for (Entry<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer>> entry  : hash1.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+"-"+entry.getValue() );

        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

With this am getting:

```
0-{1=2, 2=3, 3=4, 4=5, 6=7}

1-{1=2, 2=3, 3=4, 4=5, 6=7}

2-{1=2, 2=3, 3=4, 4=5, 6=7}
```

Can some one please help me-am new to hashmap.

Comment: Can you explain the input/output? It's a bit unclear what you want...

Comment: Do you specifically need to use a Map to represent the graph? This has a number of disadvantages - chief amongst them is that you are building in a restriction that a node may have only one edge to another node because a map enforces unique keys. Generally weighted graphs don't have this restriction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are unnecessarily overloading Map and Integer classes. Much better would be to encapsulate your graph nodes and edges in classes - this will make things much easier once you start having to perform operations on the graph:

```
class Node {
    private int id;
    private List<Edge> edges;
    public boolean hasId(int id) {
        return id == this.id;
    }
    public addEdge(Node node, int weight) {
        edges.add(new Edge(node, weight));
    }
}

class Edge {
    private int weight;
    private Node destination;
}

class Graph {
    private List<Node> nodes;
    public Node getNodeById(int id) {
        return nodes.stream()
            .filter(node -> node.hasId(id))
            .findFirst().orElse(null);
    }
}
```

I would also suggest that you break your input lines into tokens before the conversion to id and weight. This could be done inside the Graph class:

```
public void addEdge(int fromNodeID, String edgeData) {
    Node node = getNodeByID(fromNodeID);
    for (int pos = 0; pos < edgeData.length(); pos += 2) {
        int destNodeID = Integer.parseInt(edgeData.substring(pos, pos+1));
        int weight = Integer.parseInt(edgeData.substring(pos + 1, pos + 2);
        node.addEdge(getNodeByID(destNodeID), weight);
    }
}
```

Then processing input is fairly simple:

```
int id = 0;
Map<Integer, String> edgeData = new HashMap<>();
while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    graph.addNode(new Node(id));
    put(id, line);
}
edgeData.entrySet().stream()
    .forEach(entry -> graph.addEdge(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
```

I've left out a lot of error checking, simple constructors etc. but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: This is rather a good approach! but OP specifically asked for `HashMap`

Comment: @Rp- fair point. I'll add a comment asking if it really needs to be HashMap

Answer (score 0):

Here I am assuming your parsing logic is correct and that's what you want.
You need to initialize the `hash2` within the first `while` loop and you really don't need `temp1` at all.

```
int j=0;    
while ((str =in.readLine()) != null) {
            int foo = Integer.parseInt(str);
          HashMap<Integer, Integer> hash2=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
          while(foo>0){
                 remainder=foo % 10;
                   foo = foo / 10;
                 remainder2=foo%10;
                 foo=foo/10;
                 hash2.put(remainder2, remainder);
          }
          hash1.put(j, hash2);
          j++;
    }
```